# Laravel - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - at jquery.steps.min.js:6

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, laravel-5.7, jquery-steps

I have bought a html theme to use for building my project and am wanting to use the form steps displayed in the demo but when importing into my own project I am getting errors and the form styling/functionality isn't working.

[Console error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B73zp.png)

I have transferred all the files I can see in the template files to my own Laravel project but still no luck.

[How form is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8JbI.png)

Am I missing something or need to compile something? I am not good with javascript and bit confused?

Comment: Looks like you haven't included jQuery ?

Comment: you forgot to include jquery

Comment: These are in my master file?
<script src="{{ asset('/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/lib/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>